# Undefined variable in php sign up tutorial

Tags: php

I am following a tutorial on how to create a sign up page in php, but I keep getting an empty input error when I type results into the sign up section. I think that is because I am getting an error that my $result variable is undefined. I have re-watched the tutorial many times to find any typos but have ended up just exhausting myself.

This is my .signup.inc.php file

```
<?php
 // no ending tag when only php code
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {


//$ signifies a variable
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$username = $_POST["uid"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];
$pwdrepeat = $_POST["pwdrepeat"];

require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
require_once 'functions.inc.php';

if(emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) !== false) {
  header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyinput");
  exit();
}
if(invalidUid($username) !== false) {
  header("location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid");
  exit();
}
if(invalidEmail($email) !== false) {
  header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail");
 exit();
}
if(pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat) !== false) {
  header("location: ../signup.php?error=passwordsdontmatch");
  exit();
}
if(Uidexists($conn, $username, $email) !== false) {
  header("location: ../signup.php?error=usernametaken");
  exit();
}

createUser($conn, $name, $email, $username, $pwd);

}

else {
  header("location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
```

This is the start of my functions.inc.php file where the undefined $result occurs.

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
  $result;
  if(empty($name) || empty($email) ||  empty($username) ||
  empty($pwd) ||  empty($pwdrepeat)) {
    $result = true;
  }
  else {
    $result = false;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `$result` on the first line of the function? That doesn't do anything, and it's before you've done `$result = ..`. Just get rid of that line and the error will go away.

Comment: You can simplify your code with removing all the `!== false` validations. E.g. emptyInputSignup() returns boolean `true`, if any of the parameters is empty, thus `if (emptyInputSignup(parameters))` suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you just remove the first $result in the function and check again.

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
  if(empty($name) || empty($email) ||  empty($username) ||
  empty($pwd) ||  empty($pwdrepeat)) {
    $result = true;
  }
  else {
    $result = false;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

also you can do it shorthand

```
function emptyInputSignup($name, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
  return (empty($name) || empty($email) ||  empty($username) ||
      empty($pwd) ||  empty($pwdrepeat)) ?? false;
}
```